# ASP.net WebAPI Post method returns 405 when posting

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am building a controller in my Web API to allow the upload of files, specifically .MP4 files which will eventually be posted from my Unity3D app. But right now I cannot get it to accept any kind of file and I keep getting 405 results.

I am using the code from MS documentation page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2) haven't really changed anything on it other than the path. Just trying to get it to work locally on my machine first. No breakpoints are hit in debug since it is 405ing:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
{

    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }

    string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/videos");
    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

    try
    {
        // Read the form data.
        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

        // This illustrates how to get the file names.
        foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);
            Trace.WriteLine("Server file path: " + file.LocalFileName);
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
    }         
}
```

Here's system.webserver from my config:

```
<system.webServer>
<modules>
  <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>
<handlers>
  <remove name="WebDAV" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ResultHandler" path="*.mp4" verb="POST" type="FileUploadApplication.ResultHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

And here from my global.asax:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Default", 
            "{controller}/{id}", 
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
        MediaTypeFormatter());
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    }
}
```

Request header:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------- 
acebdf13572468
Host: localhost:65056
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 383829
```

Is there something that needs to be changed elsewhere? Like within IIS on the server to enable upload of specific files? I have built a simple Post method for posting images before and didn't need to do anything like that.

Any help is much appreciated on this!

**Edit:** I decorated Post() method with [HttpPost] but it still didn't work. I have also added the request header I have used.

Also in the response headers I get this:

```
Security:
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE
```

Comment: You probably need to decorate your request handler method with `[HttpPost]`.

Comment: How are you attempting to invoke the method?  Please share the request headers.

Comment: if you are posting files your content type should be 
Content-Type: multipart/form-data

Comment: @Saveen yes that is the content type.

Comment: I have changed the name of the class from VideosController to UploadController (both class and .cs file name) and for some reason it works now. I would love to know why that makes a difference.